# bootstrap on ie11 enterprise

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have written a bootstrap page and it works just perfectly on all browsers i have tested....except ie11 with enterprise mode on.

It seems to stretch everything to full width as if my screen is a giant phone. Im sure other things are broken in it but thats the first thing you see.

Anybody have any ideas if Bootstrap and Enterprise mode dont play well? I see some posts asking the question and some responses saying to force ie9 10 or edge mode but that wont work with enterprise mode as it overrides that...ie think.

Comment: Enterprise mode is effectively IE7 so Bootstrap may do all sorts of odd things.

Comment: Are you using IE7 or IE8 mode?

Comment: Are you using a proper doctype and an Enterprise Mode Site List (*sites.xml*)?

Comment: @DavidG how do i check that. AFAICS it says 'Enterprise mode on' and when i open dev tools it says 5(default) in the version number.

Comment: not sure what proper doc type is exactly but my html and css are laid out correctly yes, as far as i can see....
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx):

> Enterprise Mode, a compatibility mode that runs on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 Update and Windows 7 devices, lets websites render using a modified browser configuration that’s designed to emulate either Windows Internet Explorer 7 or Windows Internet Explorer 8, avoiding the common compatibility problems associated with web apps written and tested on older versions of Internet Explorer.

And from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browsers):

> On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11

So if you are running Enterprise mode in IE7 mode, Bootstrap will do all sorts of odd things. The solution would be to run in IE8 mode which may fix a lot of issues or don't add this site to the list.

[image]